# Cross domain ajax response failing

Tags: ajax, json, twitter, cross-domain

Ok...so ive been wriggling around with this piece of cod for quite a while now...

first i used this code which worked...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#content').html('');
$.ajax({
        url:'data.json',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
                $('#content').append(''+data.rank+'');
        }
});});
```

In this code (it works) data.json contains the JSON data in this format:

{
"user_id":"3190399",
"user_name":"Anand_Dasgupta",
"followers_current":"86",
"date_updated":"2009-06-04",
"url":"",
"avatar":"205659924/DSC09920_normal.JPG",
"follow_days":"0","started_followers":"86",
"growth_since":0,
"average_growth":"0",
"tomorrow":"86",
"next_month":"86",
"followers_yesterday":"86",
"rank":176184,
"followers_2w_ago":null,
"growth_since_2w":86,
"average_growth_2w":"6",
"tomorrow_2w":"92",
"next_month_2w":"266",
"followersperdate":[]
}

This data comes from the URL:

http://twittercounter.com/api/?username=Anand_Dasgupta&output=json&results=3
(Click the URL to get the data)

But when I replace data.json in the $.ajax function with the URL which contains the same data, this code below doesn't seem to work...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#content').html('');
$.ajax({
      url:'http://twittercounter.com/api/?username=Anand_Dasgupta&output=json&results=3',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
                $('#content').append(''+data.rank+'');
        }
});});
```

I had earlier put this question forth on StackOverflow and responses were that this is a cross domain problem.

So i read about cross domain ajax request and this is the code that i came up with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                      
    $('form#search').bind("submit", function(e){                            
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#content').html('');

// Define the callback function
  function get(jsonData) {     
     $('#content').append(''+jsonData.rank+'');
     bObj.removeScriptTag(); 
  }

// The web service call
var req  = 'http://twittercounter.com/api/?username=Anand_Dasgupta&output=json&results=3&callback=get'; 

// Create a new request object
bObj = new JSONscriptRequest(req); 

// Build the dynamic script tag
bObj.buildScriptTag(); 

// Add the script tag to the page
bObj.addScriptTag();


    });
});
```

But even doesnt seem to be working.

If anyone can provide any help then it will be deeply appreciated.
I have given the entire code so that anyone could test it themselves if they want to.

Thank you
Anand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to see if the site in question supports [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP).

You have to also use the [dataType](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) option in your ajax call set to `'jsonp'`, as well as specify the correct callback argument.